# Russian cosmonauts mistaken for ghosts because they're wearing luminous spacesuits

Tags: story-identification, tv, animated-series

This is a real long shot and may not even be classed as SF...

It's an animated TV show for children, probably one episode of an ongoing adventure series like *Jonny Quest*. I must have seen it around 1970 (maybe a year or two either way) as that's when I would have been the target age for that kind of show. It involves a group of kids who in this episode are living in a remote cabin and start seeing mysterious glowing figures moving around the woods, which they initially mistake for ghosts. They turn out to be Russian cosmonauts from a crashed lunar mission, and the reason they glow is that their spacesuits are luminous because they were planning to land on the dark side of the Moon! (Even then I knew that the Moon doesn't have a permanent dark side, though apparently the show's writers didn't!)

I don't remember anything else about it, even whether the kids were on their own or (more likely) there were adults around too, but does this ring any bells with anyone?

Comment: They could land on a night side and stay for a couple of "Earth days" during the "Moon night", so it is ok.

Comment: Maybe they were going to land at night?

Comment: I think moon missions are still sufficiently advanced that any fictional story about them is highly likely to be SF.

Comment: Scooby Doo maybe?